# Working Through Normalization (3NF)

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

I've been planning this website for a while now and began putting it together a few weeks ago and I'd say that things were going extremely well until the other day I was introduced to normalization. It's taken me quite some time to get the hang of what it is and why it's needed but I think that I'm close to acheiving my overall goal now.

So the scenario is that I have a website where members can join and set up their own newspaper/blog and assign authors to it.  The site primarily consists of a `members_table`, `authors_table`, `newspapers_table` and `posts_table`, which I've gone through and normalized to get:

**Members**

```
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+
| ID | FIRSTNAME | SURNAME  | EMAIL           | USERNAME | PASSWORD | AVATAR     | JOINED     |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+
| 01 | Brian     | Griffin  | brian@gmail.com | briang   | ***      | hdhs.jpg   | 2014-07-31 |
| 02 | Meg       | Griffin  | meg@gmail.com   | megg     | ***      |            | 2014-07-31 |
| 03 | Peter     | Griffin  | peter@gmail.com | peterg   | ***      | jaunsq.jpg | 2014-07-31 |
| 04 | Glen      | Quagmire | glen@gmail.com  | glen     | ***      |            | 2014-07-31 |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

**Authors**

```
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------+-------------------+---------+----------+---------+
| ID | FIRSTNAME | SURNAME  | EMAIL           | BIO ( REQUIRED )  | TWITTER | FACEBOOK | WEBSITE |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------+-------------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 01 | Brian     | Griffin  | brian@gmail.com | About me...       | URL     |          | URL     |
| 02 | Meg       | Griffin  | meg@gmail.com   | About me...       | URL     |          |         |
| 03 | Peter     | Griffin  | peter@gmail.com | About me...       |         | URL      | URL     |
| 04 | Glen      | Quagmire | glen@gmail.com  | About me...       | URL     | URL      |         |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------------+-------------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

** Should Socials Be Broken Down Here? If So, How?

**Newspaper_Categories**

```
+----+-------------------+
| ID | CATEGORY          |
+----+-------------------+
| 01 | Lifestyle         |
| 02 | Auto Mobiles      |
| 03 | Entertainment     |
| 04 | Food & Drink      |
| 05 | Internet          |
+----+-------------------+
```

**Newspapers**

```
+----+-----------------------+----------+---------+------------------+------------------+
| ID | NAME                  | CATEGORY | AVATAR  | BIO ( REQUIRED ) | OWNER ( MEMBER ) |
+----+-----------------------+----------+---------+------------------+------------------+
| 01 | Spooner Street Weekly | 01       | 311.jpg | About Us...      | 01               |
| 02 | A Dogs Life           | 01       |         | About Us...      | 01               |
| 03 | In The Kitchen        | 04       | js.jpg  | About Us...      | 02               |
+----+-----------------------+----------+---------+------------------+------------------+
```

Should Owner go Here or in a table named Newspaper_Owners

**Socials**

```
+----+-------------------+
| ID | TYPE              |
+----+-------------------+
| 01 | Facebook          |
| 02 | Twitter           |
| 03 | Google            |
| 04 | Flickr            |
| 05 | Youtube           |
+----+-------------------+
```

**Newspaper_Socials**

```
+----------+--------+------+
| NEWSAPER | SOCIAL | LINK |
+----------+--------+------+
| 01       | 01     | URL  |
| 01       | 02     | URL  |
| 01       | 05     | URL  |
| 01       | 01     | URL  |
| 02       | 02     | URL  |
| 02       | 04     | URL  |
| 03       | 01     | URL  |
+----------+--------+------+
```

**Post_Categories**

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
| ID | NEWSPAPER_ID | CATEGORY           |
+----+--------------+--------------------+
| 01 | 01           | Glens Girls        |
| 02 | 01           | In The Clam        |
| 03 | 01           | Peters Shenanigans |
| 04 | 02           | Martini Recipes    |
| 05 | 03           | Housewife Tips     |
+----+--------------+--------------------+
```

**Posts**

```
+----+----------+-------+---------+----------+------------+-------+
| ID | CATEGORY | TITLE | ARTICLE | FEATURED | ADDED      | VIEWS |
+----+----------+-------+---------+----------+------------+-------+
| 01 | 01       | Title | Article | 0        | 2014-07-31 | 200   |
| 02 | 01       | Title | Article | 0        | 2014-07-31 | 220   |
| 03 | 03       | Title | Article | 1        | 2014-07-31 | 232   |
| 04 | 05       | Title | Article | 0        | 2014-07-31 | 143   |
| 05 | 05       | Title | Article | 1        | 2014-07-31 | 311   |
+----+----------+-------+---------+----------+------------+-------+
```

**Post_Photos**

```
+---------+-----+--------------+------+
| POST_ID | ALT | PHOTOGRAPHER | LINK |
+---------+-----+--------------+------+
| 01      | Alt | John Smith   | URL  |
| 02      | Alt |              |      |
| 03      | Alt | Mike Jones   |      |
| 05      | Alt | Adam West    | URL  |
+---------+-----+--------------+------+
```

**Post_Keywords**

```
+---------+---------+
| POST_ID | KEYWORD |
+---------+---------+
| 01      | Keyword |
| 01      | Keyword |
| 01      | Keyword |
| 01      | Keyword |
| 02      | Keyword |
| 02      | Keyword |
| 03      | Keyword |
| 03      | Keyword |
| 03      | Keyword |
+---------+---------+
```

If each post is only allowed 3 keywords, can these be added to the end of `Posts` table?

**Author_Posts**

```
+-----------+---------+
| AUTHOR_ID | POST_ID |
+-----------+---------+
| 01        | 01      |
| 01        | 02      |
| 01        | 03      |
| 02        | 04      |
| 03        | 05      |
+-----------+---------+
```

Could anyone please let me know if I'm on the right lines with this structure and give me some pointers on where `Primary Keys` and also `Foreign Keys ???` should go?

Comment: Yes. Definitely headed in the right direction. By way of example, (author_id,post_id) is a natural composite key. It's the only key on that table and it should be PRIMARY. Alternatively, you *could* treat that as a UNIQUE KEY and have a surrogate PRIMARY KEY (e.g. `author_posts_id`) but that would only make sense if you had to refer to that table in some other context - which, in this instance, is unlikely. Similarly, (post_id,keyword) should also be PRIMARY

Comment: It would be helpful to both yourself and us if you titled your key columns with the table prefix. i.e. `MembersID` instead of just `ID`. Your results will be much more clear in multi-table queries as well.

Answer (score 1):

"** Should Socials Be Broken Down Here? If So, How?"

Yes, you already have the socials table.
Add a new many to many table of Users to Socials

Comment: Oh, no sorry, there are 2 socials - One relates to the newspaper and the other could relate to the authors

Comment: If I understand your design, I'd move 'link' from NewsPaper_Socials to the Social table.  (If Authors and NewsPaper_Socials both point to the same Social links that is...)  You already did the pattern for Newspaper_Socials.  If they point to different links, the table structure would be the same, they Ids would be different in Authors and NewsParer_Socials.  I may need clarification on the purposes if I'm off target.

Comment: Well, a newspaper may have a dedicated facebook page/twitter page, etc, etc (A Dogs Life = twitter.com/adogslife) and the Author would probably have their own profile (Peter Griffin = twitter.com/petergriffin) - So they are essecially always going to be different.  However thinking about it again, if a newspaper is based on the author (Like a persoanl blog or portfolio site) then they would likely be the same. Once again I've hit a slight problem, lol

Comment: You're on the right track.  I noticed the POST_PHOTOS are missing an idea for the PHOTO.